# ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function LetterQueryClient::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: 9

I am trying to make a plugin that connects to a json endpoint on another drupal site. But im getting an error in my service class. Please help me understand what im doing wrong.

This is my service declaration in services.yml inside the module folder:

```
services:
  letter_query_client:
    class: Drupal\******\Plugin\views\LetterQueryClient
    argument: ['@http_client_factory']
```

This is my service class:

```
namespace Drupal\*******\Plugin\Views;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;


class LetterQueryClient {

  /**
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\Client
   */
  protected $client;

  /**
   * LetterQueryClient constructor.
   *
   * @param $http_client_factory
   */
  public function __construct($http_client_factory) {
    $this->http_client_factory = $http_client_factory;
    $this->client = $http_client_factory->fromOptions([
      'base_uri' => '**********',
    ]);
  }


  public function getLetters() {
    $response = $this->client->get('********');
    $data = Json::decode($response->getBody());
    return $data;
}

}
```

This is my views query:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\*****\Plugin\views\Query;

use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Annotation\ViewsQuery;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Views query plugin
 *
 * @ViewsQuery(
 *   id = "views_*****",
 *   title = @Translation("Letter Query"),
 *   help = @Translation("Query against the API.")
 * )
 */

class ViewsLetterQuery extends QueryPluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  public function ensureTable($table, $relationship = NULL) {
    return '';
  }

  public function addField($table, $field, $alias = '', $params = []) {
    return $field;
  }

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\******\Plugin\views\LetterQueryClient
   */
  protected $LetterQueryClient;


  /**
   * ViewsLetterQuery constructor.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param $plugin_id
   * @param $plugin_definition
   * @param $LetterQueryClient
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $LetterQueryClient) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->letter_query_client = $LetterQueryClient;

  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('letter_query_client')

    );
  }

  public function execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
    $index = 0;
    if ($letter_items = $this->LetterQueryClient->getLetters()) {
      foreach ($letter_items as $letter_item) {
        $row['title'] = $letter_item['title'];
        $row['field_note'] = $letter_item['field_note'];
        $row['index'] = $index++;
        $view->result[] = new ResultRow($row);

      }

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you did not define the service in services.yml with an argument to construct it with.

Comment: How are you invoking this class? You've put it in a Plugin namespace, but I'm not sure if you intended to use Drupal's plugin system (typically a Drupal plugin has an annotation, for one; for another, I'm not sure that "Plugin\Views" is a namespace that Views module uses).

Comment: Kevin I added the code to my declaration of the service in the service.yml file.

Comment: Les I am trying to make a views plugin. I tweaked the namespace a bit to match the namespace of the view per your suggestions. Also i added the rest of my code.

Comment: You just have a typo - `argument` should be `arguments` in .services.yml

Comment: That was part of it Clive. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* type-hint the parameters of your service's constructor, otherwise Symfony's auto-wire will not work:

```
namespace Drupal\*******\Plugin\Views;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;


class LetterQueryClient {

  /**
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\Client
   */
  protected $client;

  /**
   * LetterQueryClient constructor.
   *
   * @param $http_client_factory
   */
  public function __construct(Drupal\Core\Http\ClientFactory $http_client_factory) { // type-hint here
    $this->http_client_factory = $http_client_factory; // side note: this member variable is not defined
    $this->client = $http_client_factory->fromOptions([
      'base_uri' => '**********',
    ]);
  }
```

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried the type hint approach. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Same for the views plugin (after the first three Drupal-plugin-specific parameters)

Comment: So I added the namespace for http_client_factory in the parameter annotation and that worked. Is that what you meant? I couldn't find anything in the documentation as to why it works that way.